# selecting multiple items form multiple tables with min and max

Tags: mysql, sql, join, multiple-tables

I'm having a little trouble figuring out this SQL statement. I have three tables `employee`, `job`, and `job type`.

`job type` is reference table. It has the name of the job, how long that job takes, and how much is charged for that job.

`job` has records of what job was performed for what client by which employee and the date performed. It links to `job type` `jobname`.

`employee` has name of employee, and `employee id`. It links to `job` table by `employee id`.

I need to display a list of all employees as well as the cheapest and most expensive jobs they did for a given year.

I think I will probably have to have an embedded select and a few `joins`. Maybe a `union`The complexity is just too far out of my experience. I'm not even sure where to being to be honest.

Comment: Give your tables columns detail and what queries you tried, please.

Comment: Would be better if you provide sample data and expected output too.

Comment: Here is a quick visual of the table:
http://pastebin.com/RYaCFHia
Each employee has performed three jobs. I haven't tried any queries yet because I'm not ever really sure how to go about it.

Comment: Output:
employee     min-cost     max-cost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `employee` table as the primary table in your query so you will get one row per employee, even if that employee is associated to 0 jobs. Then use outer joins to the `job` and `job_type` tables, group by the employee identifiers, and use the `min()` and `max()` aggregate functions on the job table to select the min and max job costs (if any).

Something like this should help you get started:

```
select employee.employee_id ,
  employee.employee_name, 
  min(job_type.cost),
  max(job_type.cost)
from employee 
  left outer join job on job.employee_id = employee.employee_id
  left outer join job_type on job_type.job_type_id = job.job_type_id
group by employee.employee_id, 
  employee.employee_name
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. I haven't had something that complex so I wasn't even sure where to begin with the logic.